# Como Activar un Elemento Li desde la url

Tags: javascript, html, mvc

Hola tengo un listado de 3 elementos y necesito saber como puedo poner un elemento de esa lista class="active"desde una llamada con @UrlAction.
Gracias de ante mano

### INDEX DONDE SE ENCUENTRA EL LISTADO EL ELEMENTO ES TRACKING

```
@{if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <div class="mi-copa-box mt-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <ul class="copa-box-list">
                        <li id="#mi_copa_box" class="active"><i class="fas fa-laptop"></i> @Resources.Resource.mi_copa_box</li>
                        <li id="#registrate"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> @Resources.Resource.registrate</li>
                        <li id="#tracking"><i class="fas fa-plane"></i> @Resources.Resource.tracking</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9 form-content">
                    <div class="box" id="mi_copa_box" style="display: block">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-mi-copa-box" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div style="box-sizing: border-box; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 7px">
                                    <label for="txtUsuario" class="text-center small">@Resources.Resource.nombreusuario</label>
                                    <input id="txtUsuario" type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="Email" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div style="box-sizing: border-box; padding-left: 7px; padding-left: 15px">
                                    <label for="txtPassword" class="text-center small">@Resources.Resource.contrasena</label>
                                    <input id="txtPassword" type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                                    <input style="width: 70%; margin-left: 15%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="@Resources.Resource.ingresar" />
                                    <a href="@(Url.Action("ContrasenaOlvidada","Home"))" class="text-center w-100 small float-left underline" style="margin-top: 10px;">@Resources.Resource.olvidosucontrasena</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" id="registrate">
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <p class="gray" style="box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 0.9rem;padding-top: 4.3rem;padding: 40px 80px 0px;">@Resources.Resource.registrateencopabox</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 p-4">
                            <a href="@(Url.Action("Registrate","Account"))" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-100 mt-4">@Resources.Resource.crearCuenta</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" id="tracking" style="padding-top: 2.2rem" name="tracking">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label for="txtTracking" class="w-100 text-center" style="font-size: 0.9rem;padding-top: 4px;">@Resources.Resource.ingresaTracking</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input id="txtTracking" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="tracking" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 px-5">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-100" value="@Resources.Resource.buscar" onclick="enviarTracking();" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="tracking-result" class="box" style="padding-top: 2.2rem; display:none;">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div id="screen">
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="marca-origen"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></li>
                                    <li id="marca-transito"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></li>
                                    <li id="marca-destino"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="row pt-2">
                                    <div class="col-4"><label id="origen-tracking" class="etiqueta-tracking">@Resources.Resource.recibido</label><label id="fecha-origen-tracking" class="etiqueta-tracking"></label></div>
                                    <div class="col-4"><label id="transito-tracking" class="etiqueta-tracking">@Resources.Resource.transito</label><label id="fecha-transito-tracking" class="etiqueta-tracking"></label></div>
                                    <div class="col-4"><label id="destino-tracking" class="etiqueta-tracking">@Resources.Resource.listoretiro</label><label id="fecha-destino-tracking" class="etiqueta-tracking"></label></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
    else
    {

        <div class="mi-copa-box mi-copa-box-autenticado mt-4">
            <div class="row" style="min-height:134px;">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <ul class="copa-box-list">
                        <li id="#mi_copa_box" class="active"><i class="fas fa-laptop"></i> @Resources.Resource.mi_copa_box</li>
                        <li id="#tracking"><i class="fas fa-plane"></i> @Resources.Resource.tracking</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9 form-content">
                    <div class="box" id="mi_copa_box" style="display: block">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-mi-copa-box" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div style="box-sizing: border-box; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 7px">
                                    <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">@($"{Resources.Resource.hola} {User.Identity.GetFieldValue("Nombre")},")</p>
                                    <p>@Resources.Resource.infoperfil <a href="@(Url.Action("Index", "AreaPrivada"))">@Resources.Resource.aqui</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">

                                <a href="@(Url.Action("Index","AreaPrivada"))" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-100 mt-5">@Resources.Resource.mi_copa_box</a>

                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" id="tracking" style="padding-top: 3rem">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label for="txtTracking" class="gray w-100 text-center" style="font-size: 0.9rem;padding-top: 4px;">@Resources.Resource.ingresaTracking</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input id="txtTracking" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="usuario" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 px-5">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-100" value="Buscar" onclick="enviarTracking();" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }

}
```

---

### SECCIÓN CON EL LINK A TRACKING

@Resources.Resource.respuestafaq5  **@Resources.Resource.tracking**

Comment: Has intentado algo? Si es asi publica tu codigo para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Si he intentado varias cosas pero sin resultado ahora añado el codigo

Comment: Basado en que queres que use, o no la clase `active`? según la página donde está o según que criterio?

Comment: Hola Juan Salvador la idea es que cuando haga click en el enlace tracking me lleve a la pagina donde esta el <ul> con el item tracking activo.

Answer (score 0):

tenes varias opciones para hacer lo que buscas, una, sería, usar un [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) con el objeto `ViewContext`

Por ejemplo

```
<ul class="copa-box-list">
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Menu" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Menu1", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Menu2" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Menu2", "Menu2", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Menu3" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Menu3", "Menu3", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

En el ejemplo, uso el operador ternario para chequear la ruta actual, si coincide con `Menu` añado la clase `active` al primer li, caso contrario, no lo hago (y así lo chequeo en los otros dos items del menú).

---

Otra posibilidad, es crear un Custom HtmlHelper realizar esta validación, tome uno de la [respuesta de Prof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29968637/5213794) en StackOverflow en Inglés que me pareció muy interesante

> Extensión:
>
> ```
> public static MvcHtmlString LiActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string text, string action, string controller)
> {
>     var context = html.ViewContext;
>     if (context.Controller.ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
>         context = html.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext;
>     var routeValues = context.RouteData.Values;
>     var currentAction = routeValues["action"].ToString();
>     var currentController = routeValues["controller"].ToString();
>
>     var str = String.Format("<li role=\"presentation\"{0}>{1}</li>",
>         currentAction.Equals(action, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) &&
>         currentController.Equals(controller, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) ?
>         " class=\"active\"" :
>         String.Empty, html.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString()
>     );
>     return new MvcHtmlString(str);
> }
> ```
>
> Uso:
>
> ```
> <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
>     @Html.LiActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
>     @Html.LiActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")
> </ul>
> ```

En tu caso, deberías utilizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<ul class="copa-box-list">
    @Html.LiActionLink("Menu1", "Index", "Home")
    @Html.LiActionLink("Menu2", "Menu2", "Home")
    @Html.LiActionLink("Menu3", "Menu3", "Home")
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya lo pruebo a ver que tal me va.
Gracias.